# What do you call rings that have unique factorizations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring, integers, prime-factorization

For example, integers, gaussian integers, and polynomials all have unique factorizations. What are these rings (or this property) referred to as? Or is unique factorization a ubiquitous property that applies to all rings? If not, what is an example of a ring that doesn't have any meaningful "unique factorization" property?

I'm no expert at abstract algebra, so sorry if this is a silly question, or I'm using the term "ring" incorrectly (perhaps field or group is the more applicable term).

Comment: Paste your title into google and click "*I'm feeling lucky*" ;-)

Comment: @dxiv My bad >.<. Thanks <3

Comment: Yes... always worth briefly researching before asking. I am pretty sure you mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain

Comment: Unique factorization (or factorial) ring / domain. Please delete the question since it is a dupe.

Comment: @DietrichBurde yeah, I meant to say "Abstract Algebra", but slipped up and wrote "Algebraic Geometry" without thinking >.<.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is [Unique Factorization Domains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain). Thanks Google and Wikipedia!